# Free() statement CRASH? Help this function works out :(

Tags: c, list, function, memory, free

I'm having problems with this function:

```
 struct list{
        int x;
        int y;
        struct list *next_ptr;
    };


  boolean funzione_esame(struct list **ptrptr, int *number){
        if(*ptrptr != NULL){
        struct list *tmp;
        struct list *pos;
        pos=(*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
        *number=1;
        while(pos != NULL){
            if(pos->x <= (*ptrptr)->y){
                pos->x=(*ptrptr)->y;
                if(pos->x >= pos->y){
                    tmp=pos;
                    pos=pos->next_ptr;
                    free(tmp);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            pos=pos->next_ptr;
            ptrptr=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
            (*number)++;
            }
        return TRUE;
        } else return FALSE;
    }
```

I don't waste time explain you what it should do etc.etc. but I just can't understand why it crashes at the line **free(tmp);** .. 
I think I did all good, there aren't errors of any kind. Maybe it's a memory problem and the solution is very easy but I really can't find it ^^
 Just tell me if you need more infos or if I'm not very clear. And sorry for my "maccheroni english" :P.
Thanks in advance fellas!

Comment: So, did you try it in a debugger and check the value of `tmp` before the crash? When does it crash, directly on the first value of `pos`?

Comment: Likely a double-free or something like that. Use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to gather the report about memory allocations and deallocations.

Comment: Will do, I'll let you know.

Comment: Cant help you if you do not show the function that are allocating the memory.

Comment: So in the debugger this is the error I get and it happens in this line everytime there's the assignment pos=pos->next_ptr;  :
if(pos->x >= pos->y){
   tmp=pos;
   **pos=pos->next_ptr;**
   free(tmp);
   continue;

pos | struct list * | Error: Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-update 1 var17 Error message from debugger back end: Cannot access memory at address 0x8\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-update 1 var17 Error message from debugger back end: Cannot access memory at address 0x8

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to check the whole program and function here it is:
[http://pastebin.com/eFk8R2a6](http://pastebin.com/eFk8R2a6)

Answer (score -1):

If you call free on an unallocated memory address then it crashes. Use this:

```
if(tmp != NULL) free(tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't change anything. tmp is first assigned with pos (tmp=pos) so it's not an unallocated memory address.<br>Anyway, I tryed both way and still nothing. This time it doesn't crash, it's just that free doesn't delete the allocated memory.<br>
This is the function input: (1,2), (3,6), (4,8), (5,7), (6,9)<br>
This is the function (wrong) output: (1,2), (3,6), (6,8), (4074216,4074064), (8,9)<br>While the correct output should be: (1,2), (3,6), (6,8), (8,9)

Comment: The if condition in `if(tmp != NULL) free(tmp)` is not needed. Calling `free(NULL)` is well defined, and does nothing. @Barnercart free() doesn't necessarily "delete" memory. The content might stick around, or it might not - trying to access something you have free()'d is undefined behavior and doing so could crash, could work, or it could cause problems later on.

Comment: Well, I used to use free() that way and never got me problems :/ 
What can I do to "delete" that memory allocation then? The function requires to delete unecessary elements and that output just can't work :D

Comment: @Barnercart You just call free() when you are done with that piece of memory. And then you make 100% sure your code does not access the memory that you have free'd.

Comment: That's correct but what if I have to delete that memory more than once? It's what the function has to do, everytime there's that certain condition it goes to the next element and delete the previous one.